# Django returning said rows in a queryset

Tags: python, django

Using a queryset in Django (in a view) I only want to get said rows 51-100. i.e. I only want it to return these rows.

is this possible and how within .

```
 objectQuerySet = Recipient.objects.filter(incentiveid=incentive).order_by('fullname')
```

I don't want to use any paging system etc this is just a one time thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) to execute a `LIMIT` `OFFSET` statement:

```
objectQuerySet = Recipient.objects.filter(incentiveid=incentive).order_by('fullname')[51:100]
```